# How to solve uncontrolled warning in react formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

Let's say we have a form that has two fields, first name, and last name.

I want to control this form using React Formik and I have simulated API response using `setTimeout`

The problem is that when API returns null for some properties, I get the dirty uncontrolled warning of React.

I'm using Formik's 'name' prop to mutually bind my JSON to my form inputs.

How can I solve this problem?

Here's my code:

```
export default function Home() {
  const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(initialValues);
  }, [initialValues]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setInitialValues({ firstName: 'api', lastName: null });
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
  };

  const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    firstName: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    lastName: Yup.string().required('Required'),
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        validateOnChange={false}
        validateOnBlur={false}
        enableReinitialize
      >
        <Form>
          <br />
          <div>
            <Field
              type="text"
              id="firstName"
              name="firstName"
              label="firstName"
              placeholder="First Name"
            />

            <ErrorMessage name="firstName" />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div>
            <Field
              type="text"
              id="lastName"
              name="lastName"
              placeholder="Last Name"
            />
            <ErrorMessage name="lastName" />
          </div>
          <br />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[And here's an online sample in StackBlits](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-hnybjg?file=package.json,pages%2Findex.js)

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust the data coming back from your API to be complete, then. Pull each value you need into a new object with a default value of an empty string. Something like

```js
let newInitialValues = {};
newInitialValues.firstName = apiResult.firstName ? apiResult.firstName : '';
newInitialValues.lastName = apiResult.lastName ? apiResult.lastName : '';
```

This ensures you'll always have a valid value.